# DDD - storing Domain Objects in document oriented storages, PostgreSQL, MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, postgresql, doctrine-orm, domain-driven-design

One more question regarding DDD. Thinking of persisting my aggregates (I don't wish to use Event Sourcing) I searched over the internet and found very interesting [article](https://kalele.io/the-ideal-domain-driven-design-aggregate-store/) by Vaughn Vernon. Briefly - the author praises concept of storing Domain Objects with the whole structure using document oriented storages, particularly PostgreSQL.

My question is - as I'm new to DDD concept - is it common in DDD development to use this approach? I mean to store aggregates as serialized complete documents using document-oriented storage?
I think persisting aggregates in theirs nested way is closer to DDD idea, than loading it and mapping using ORM. Document format seems to be more natural and elastic for nested structure of Domain Objects.
Besides the article mentioned above, I'm failing to find some more comments about this concept.

The next question is - in PHP environment - has anyone tried to tie it with Doctrine2 ? It seems it could automatically serialize POPOs and it is possible to use ValueObjects some way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

> My question is - as I'm new to DDD concept - is it common in DDD development to use this approach?

Yes - ish.

One thing to keep in mind: DDD is intended to assist in correctly modeling the business.  If *change* is an valuable property for the domain to have (likely to be the case if this project is one which represents a competitive advantage to your business), then you need to be thinking about aggregate serialization that is easily migrated to improved models.  In other words, how do you map a representation of the old model to the new model?

If you are taking this approach, then you may also want to look into [cqrs](/questions/tagged/cqrs); blobs of data are satisfactory for the write use cases, but write only domain models don't offer very much business value.  You may have an easier time developing an eventually consistent read model rather than trying to build out complex projections on demand from a document store.

The other place you see a similar approach is solutions that use event sourced aggregates; writes are achieved by appending to a history, and the actual state involved in any given change is normally stored in a blob.

Answer (score 1):

As you might know from the book, aggregates persistence is done by using the Repository pattern. Its purpose is to hide persistence technology and implementation details from the domain model.

Repositories by definition can store and retrieve whole aggregates only. This is why Vernon mentions document-like storage as a good candidate. When using RDBMS for aggregate persistence, you often end up using ORMs and complex mappings. When going this path, you get complex schemas and not optimal queries, cumbersome update logic and so on.

This is indeed why CQRS got traction especially in the DDD community, because traditional "collection-style" repositories lack any ability to query many aggregates and retrieve some "reporting-style" data. The blue book suggests some rather complex way to do this. CQRS eliminates this issue but requires quite a bit of extra work to keep two models synchronised.

There is also another approach to deal with it. Usually, the domain model has no need to run queries on aggregates. A "client" of the domain model is responsible to send a proper "command" or request to the domain model to be handled by some kind of an application service. This "client" part or "adapter" part in hexagon architecture, can run queries on the domain persistence database without using any repositories. It is sort of CQRS as well but using one database.